# Team Foundation Server: granting Check-out Rights on a whole Collection

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to grant an Windows Group Rights "Reading Rights" to an whole Collection?

By "Reading Rights" I mean that anyone in this Group can get the Sources out of TFS but can not check-in something or Edit "Tasks" oder Launch Builds or anything else.

I found no such things in the Security Settings of the "Team Foundation Administration Console" on the Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a much easier way to do this.  Open up Source Control Explorer for the Team Project Collection you would like to set this permission on.  In the tree-view on the left, right-click the top-most node (which likely has your collection name in it) and select "Security".  This will bring up the security options that take precedence over the whole collection.

From here, find the group that you would like to grant this permission to and select them.  Next, in the permissions area, grant them the "Read" permission.  This will allow everyone in that group to view and download the source in that Team Project Collection.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

-Taylor, TFS Version Control Development Lead

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by customizing the process by changing the permission for the contributions group which I not recommended, or by adding new group which has your needed permissions, see the following image

**Note**: you can do this by Process Editor using TFPT ([Team Foundation Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)) or by customizing the XML files directly.

[image]